# Issue on Abstract pure virtual function Run time Segment Fautl

Tags: c++

At the following code I"m trying to implement Sean Parent"s Better Code Run Time  Polymorphism. My questions are

1) When I try to define the methods of struct TConcept as abstract virtual the code does not compile. The error messages are very criptic. Can someone explain me how to fix this problem

2) When I try to insert  the following line at main function and try to run the snippet I·m getting Segment fault error. How can I fix it.

//    Document.emplace_back(Document);

Thanks

Sabetay

I"m using  the following online C++ compiler.
https://wandbox.org/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>    // std::reverse
template<typename T>
void draw(ostream& os, const T& Entry)  {
    os << Entry << endl;
}
class TObject {
public :
    template<typename T>
    TObject(T Entry) : Self(make_unique<TModel<T>>(move(Entry))) {}
    friend void draw(ostream& os, const TObject& Entry) {
        Entry.Self->ModelDraw(os);
    }
    TObject(const TObject& Entry) : Self(Entry.Self->Copy()) {}
    TObject& operator=(TObject& Entry) { return *this = TObject(Entry); }
    TObject(TObject&& Entry) noexcept = default;
    TObject& operator=(TObject&& Entry) noexcept = default;
private :
    struct TConcept {
        virtual ~TConcept() = default;
        virtual void ModelDraw(ostream& os) const {} //  Must be abstract function
        virtual unique_ptr<TConcept> Copy() const {} //  Must be abstract function
    };
    template<typename T>   
    struct TModel final : TConcept {
        T Data;
        TModel(T Entry) : Data(move(Entry)) { } 
        void ModelDraw(ostream& os) const override {
            draw(os, Data);    
        }
        unique_ptr<TConcept> Copy() { return make_unique<TConcept>(*this); }
    };
    unique_ptr<TConcept > Self;
};
using TDocument = vector<TObject>;
void draw(ostream& os, const TDocument& vDoc) {
    os << " Document Start" << endl;
    for(auto& Entry : vDoc)
        draw(os, Entry);
    os << " Document End " << endl;
}
int main() {
TDocument Document;
    Document.reserve(5);
    Document.emplace_back(0);
    Document.emplace_back(1);
    Document.emplace_back(" Hello World ");
    Document.emplace_back(Document); // This line is giving Segment fault why
    reverse(Document.begin(), Document.end());
    draw(cout,Document);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The `Copy()` function in `TModel` differs in constness from the `Copy() const` in the base class. So it is not an override, making the derived class also abstract.

2) I don't know what you intend `Document.emplace_back(Document);` to do. To me it looks like it is trying to insert `Document` into itself.

<strike>If nothing else, `Document` stores elements of type `TObject`, not of type `TDocument`, so this is not going to work.</strike>

---

Looking further, `Document` is storing objects holding *pointers* to other objects (well hidden in the nested classes). So possibly it could hold a wrapped pointer to itself.

The primary problem with `Document.emplace_back(Document);` is that the overridden `Copy()` function tries to do `return make_unique<TConcept>(*this);`. However, `make_unique<TConcept>` will attempt to do a `new TConcept(parameters)`, which doesn't work when `TConcept` is abstract.

I can get the code to compile and run by modifying the `TModel::Copy` function into this rather nasty piece:

```
unique_ptr<TConcept> Copy() const override 
{ return unique_ptr<TConcept>(new TModel(*this)); }
```

Whether it now does anything useful, I still cannot tell.  :-)

Comment: -watch that video and youll understand what am I asking

Comment: Ok, I've tried to dig a bit deeper and added a new section to the answer.